# How to add a structure to a vector's front?

Tags: c++, vector, std

```
int main ()
{
    vector<int> myvector (3,100);

    int myarray [] = { 501,502,503 };
    myvector.insert (myvector.begin(), myarray, myarray+3);

    return 0;
}
```

That works.

This doesn't:

```
typedef struct
{
    float latitude;
    float longitude;
} coordinate;

int main ()
{
    std :: vector <coordinate> previousPoints;

    coordinate start;
    start.latitude  = 22.3;
    start.longitude = 33.4;
    previousPoints.insert (previousPoints.begin (), start, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
anisha@linux-trra:~> g++ y.cpp 
y.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
y.cpp:18:58: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<coordinate>::insert(std::vector<coordinate>::iterator, coordinate&, int)’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/vector.tcc:106:5: note: candidates are: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::insert(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, const value_type&) [with _Tp = coordinate, _Alloc = std::allocator<coordinate>, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<coordinate*, std::vector<coordinate> >, typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer = coordinate*, value_type = coordinate]
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/stl_vector.h:858:7: note:                 void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::insert(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, std::vector::size_type, const value_type&) [with _Tp = coordinate, _Alloc = std::allocator<coordinate>, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<coordinate*, std::vector<coordinate> >, typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer = coordinate*, std::vector::size_type = long unsigned int, value_type = coordinate]
anisha@linux-trra:~>
```

What's the error talking about? How are the both examples different?

Comment: Don't feel stupid about this error: C++ compiler error messages are basically useless... they mean "There is an error here but I'not going to tell you what it is... neener neener". They are so bad that there are even companies that make a living just out of decipherning error messages.

Comment: @6502 The first line is quite telling: it says the constructor the code is attempting to use does not exist.

Comment: @juanchopanza: the real fun begins when you just forget about a const in another file and the error message start babbling screenfulls of nonsense directly from the guts of standard include file with names with more underscore than regular characters. In this specific case the error was ok (for a C++ setting). But a good error would have been "missing & before second parameter"...

Comment: @6502 I would find the error message you propose more confusing, and would have led to using a weird solution (adding the `&` and so on).

Comment: @juanchopanza the solution given by WhozCraig is about adding the "&", which works.

Comment: @juanchopanza: actually indeed adding a `&` is an invalid solution (you can use the address of "past the last" element of an array, but you cannot formally use the address `&start+1` with a regular variable.

Comment: @6502 refers to this and indeed it is not standard, more than anything to discount the completely valid potential of an operator&() override. Interestingly, the now-three implementations of STL I have dug into implement the single-insert-by-ref by prompting through a formal reference, then taking the address of the reference and performing the same pointer arithmetic, with both eventually leading to the same call. But I agree with 6502; although it works, it is certainly not in congruence with the standard. Had you override operator&() it would most-certainly *not* have worked.

Comment: @AnishaKaul that being the case (see above) I would ask that you mark juanchopanza's answer as the correct one. It is perfectly valid, and follows the standard.

Comment: @WhozCraig Now, I've read your conversation in below comments, and I'll do as you say! :) Thanks for your help, BTW.

Comment: @WhozCraig: If you are interested in where it's said that you cannot use pointer arithmetic on anything except pointers to array elements please see `5.7 Additive operators` at paragraph 5 where it's discussed `pointer+-integer` and in particular last phrase.

Comment: @6502 It makes perfect sense both in the standard and when you put it as you did. As soon as I thought of a operator &() override I was like "duh" that can't be a general solution. Every day I think I know more, I discover how little I know. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no three parameter [std::vector::insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) method taking a value as second argument. If you want to insert at the front, you could try

```
previousPoints.insert(previousPoints.begin(), start);
```

By the way, if you are going to be performing this operation often, on large vectors, you may want to consider using an `std::deque` instead, and using it's [push_front](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/push_front) method, which has complex time complexity.

Comment: @AnishaKaul nope. There is `site_type` or `InputIterator` as second parameter for the three parameter variants.

Comment: @AnishaKaul for what its worth, the three parameter member that may have confused you is the replicator, which makes 'n' copies of the value passed.

Comment: @AnishaKaul: note that the answer you accepted is indeed invalid C++ code (relies on undefined behavior). This solution is the only technically correct to your question.

Comment: @6502 Thanks for pointing out. I've done that. And juan, thanks for the hint about deque.